# Do SN2 reactions always invert absolute configuration?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I know that an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction proceeds through complete inversion of configuration, but is it necessary that the absolute configuration (*R*/*S*) of the chiral centre change after an $\mathrm{S_N2}$ attack ?

Comment: No, it is not.Why do you think it should?

Comment: Short answer: No

Answer (score 6):

For the ease of thinking about this, let's imagine $\mathrm{S_N2}$ attack of $\ce{CN-}$ on [bromochlorofluoroiodomethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromochlorofluoroiodomethane), where iodide is being displaced.

[image: SN2]

Absolute stereochemistry is retained in this case because the highest priority substituent is becoming the lowest priority substituent. If you were to find the absolute stereochemistry of $\ce{2 ->3->4}$ in (*R*)-bromochlorofluoroiodomethane, which becomes $\ce{1->2->3}$ after attack, you would see that it is *S* and after attack becomes *R*. You can see that here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The assigned configuration is based on the substituents at the stereocenter.  If what is entering has a different prority than what is leaving relative to the other groups, there may be no change in R/S.

For example:

The SN2 reaction of cyanide with MeCClHCH(SEt)2; in this case S alkyl chloride-->S nitrile (or R-->R) because the -CH(SEt)2 substituent is higher priority than -CN. The -Cl was 1st priority in the starting material.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether the $S_N2$ substitution inverts $R/S$ configuration, just do some simple arithmetic.

Let $Nu$ be the nucleophile, $L$ be the leaving group, and $R_1,R_2, R_3$ be the remaining groups.  $L$ will be higher in priority than 0, 1, 2, or 3 of the groups, and similarly for $Nu$.  You work out the difference between the two correct numbers for your specific reaction.  If it's even, you invert absolute configuration, if it's odd, you don't.  For example, in @Ringo's example above the leaving group, iodide, is higher than 3 of the retained groups but cyanide is higher than 0.  These numbers have an odd difference --> absolute configuration is retained.